# Compile with standalone flag gives compilation errors in client code

Tags: f#, compiler-errors

I'm attempting to compile [Zero29](https://github.com/ploeh/ZeroToNine) with the `--standalone` compiler flag. The project itself compiles fine, but I have a unit test project that exercises some code in the Zero29 project, even though it's an executable program (.exe).

Everything works fine *without* the `--standalone` compilation flag.

However, when I add the `--standalone` compilation flag to the Zero29 project, the Zero29 project compiles fine, but in the unit test project, the compiler complains about this Discriminated Union [defined in the Zero29 project](https://github.com/ploeh/ZeroToNine/blob/863554cb5243839791bc4971e152bbf15a45c3db/Src/Zero29/Args.fs#L6-L12):

```
namespace Ploeh.ZeroToNine

open System
open Ploeh.ZeroToNine.Versioning

type Arg =
    | Assign of Version
    | AssignRank of Rank * int
    | Increment of Rank
    | ListVersions
    | ShowHelp
    | Unknown of string list
```

The unit test project directly references the Zero29 project:

> Zero29.UnitTests --references--> Zero29 (where --standalone is added)

When I attempt to compile the entire solution, the Zero29 project compiles with the `--standalone` flag, but then compilation of Zero29.UnitTests fails. There are several errors, but they are all the same, so here's a single example:

> error FS0039: The value or constructor 'Assign' is not defined

Which points to the third line of [this code](https://github.com/ploeh/ZeroToNine/blob/863554cb5243839791bc4971e152bbf15a45c3db/Src/Zero29.UnitTests/ArgsTests.fs#L53-L55):

```
let ParseAssignVersionReturnsCorrectResult(version : string) =
    let actual = [| "-a"; version |] |> Args.Parse
    verify <@ [Assign(Version version)] = (actual |> Seq.toList) @>
```

The strange thing is that while the compiler complains about `Assign` in the third line of this code snippet, it *doesn't* complain about the use of `Args.Parse`, even though it's [defined in the same code file as the `Arg` Discriminated Union](https://github.com/ploeh/ZeroToNine/blob/863554cb5243839791bc4971e152bbf15a45c3db/Src/Zero29/Args.fs#L26-L44).

Why does it do that, and how can I resolve this issue?

(I've attempted to distil the problem here, but the links I've provided point to the actual code files on GitHub, if more information is required.)

Comment: This looks like a bug in the F# Compiler (fsc.exe) since the build arguments are exactly the same when the Zero29 project is compiled with and without the `--standalone` compiler flag.

Comment: I can't say that the thought didn't cross my mind, by I always hesitate to say that *Select is Broken*...

Comment: It seems that in the case Zero29 is compiled with the `--standalone` flag, Args.Assign and friends appear as "Nested types". When Zero29 is compiled without the `--standalone` flag, "Assign" becomes a "Union case Args.Assign". It seems the compiler is omitting something in the standalone case. A possible next step is to look at the generated types. Some relevant discussion seems to be here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17832203/is-f-aware-of-its-discriminated-unions-compiled-forms

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Libraries compiled with the `--standalone` switch cannot expose any F# datatypes. This is, for one, expressly stated in Pickering (2007), p. 210. In your case, a discriminated union is one of these prohibited types. The fact that the file is an executable changes nothing here: it becomes a library the moment you attempt to use it as one.

There have been also multiple reports (for example, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28098961/1149924) and [here](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/fsharp-opensource/r_5AEGqijZI/tHLbjCTCEtoJ)) that even libraries compiled with `--standalone` behave, quoting one of these sources, “funky.” It would be safe to say that the use of this switch should perhaps be limited to stand-alone executables only (and they cannot pretend to be a library even when under unit tests).

---

Pickering R. (2007). *Foundations of F#*. Apress.